# regex repeated character count

Tags: java, regex, character, repeat

If I have a set of characters like "abcdefghij" and using this characters, I generate random a password using this characters. A generated password can have, for example, 6 characters. How to validate a password using regex so that tho neighbor characters are not identical and a character does not repeat more that twice?

Comment: In what programming language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
/^
  (?:(.)
     (?!\1)           # neighbor characters are not identical
     (?!(?>.*?\1){2}) # character does not occur more than twice
  )*
\z/x
```

Perl quoting, the atomic group can be removed if not supported.

---

In Java regex it could be written like:

```
^(?:(.)(?!\1|(?:.*?\1){2}))*\z
```

Comment: Clever! (and well documented) +1

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK, this cannot be done with a simple regexp (particularly, ensuring that a letter only appears twice at max. You could do a bunch of expressions like

```
[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*))
[^b]*(b[^b]*(b[^b]*))
....
```

and also (matching means the validation failed):

```
[^a]*aa[^a]*
[^b]*bb[^b]*
```

but obviously this is not good idea.

The condition that the characters do not repeat together maybe can treated with capturing groups, but I am almost sure the other one cannot be checked with regex.

BTW... why the obsession with regex? Programming these checks are trivial, regex is useful in a set of cases but not every check can be done with regex.