# Is there any utlity method in Java to find repeating duplicate characters?

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there any utility method in java to find the repeating duplicate character in java?

e.g. "allowed" is not allowed as it has two repeating 'l' and "repeating" is allowed though it has two 'e'

I was looking at the `StringUtils`, but doesn't have anything there. I am thinking to write something like

```
for (each char in string) {
if (char at counter of loop == char at next counter) {
break;
}}
```

Comment: That sounds fairly specific and I'm not sure you will find a library that does exactly that. Writing the loop is probably going to take you less time than checking available libraries (and possibly typing this question)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no utility method for this as I don't think this problem is common enough to actually deserve one. It far too specific for any general use.

Make your own method just as you suggested, it seems fine.

Answer (score 3):

The loop approach is one solution or, if you want something fancy, you could use a [regex approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929614/regex-repeated-character-count), which would look like:

```
private static final Pattern repeatMatcher = Pattern.compile("^(?:(.)(?!\\1))*$");

public static boolean hasRepeatedCharacters(String input) {
    return !repeatMatcher.matcher(input).matches();
}
```

But the basic approach with a loop is certainly more readable:

```
public static boolean hasRepeatedCharacters(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i + 1)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like a common usecase for an utility. Your code logic seems good enough. Optimization to check if it's single char or not and check for char at next counter doesn't exceed string length should do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Character last = null;
boolean allowed = true;

for (Character c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (c.equals(last)) {
        allowed = false;
        break;
    }
    last = c.charValue();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this a well:

```
package com.stack.overflow.works.main;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * @author sarath_sivan
 */

public class DuplicatesFinder {

    public static void findDuplicates(String inputString) {
        Map<Character, Integer> duplicatesMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); 
        char[] charArray = inputString.toCharArray();
        for (Character ch : charArray) {
            if (duplicatesMap.containsKey(ch)) {
                duplicatesMap.put(ch, duplicatesMap.get(ch) + 1);
            } else {
                duplicatesMap.put(ch, 1);
            }
        }
        Set<Character> keySet = duplicatesMap.keySet();
        for (Character ch: keySet) {
            if (duplicatesMap.get(ch) > 1) {
                System.out.println("[INFO: CHARACTER " + ch + " IS DUPLICATE, OCCURENCE: " + duplicatesMap.get(ch) + " TIMES]");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DuplicatesFinder.findDuplicates("sarath kumar sivan");
    }

}
```

It will produce the simple test result for the input string "sarath kumar sivan" like this:

```
[INFO: CHARACTER   IS DUPLICATE, OCCURENCE: 2 TIMES]
[INFO: CHARACTER s IS DUPLICATE, OCCURENCE: 2 TIMES]
[INFO: CHARACTER r IS DUPLICATE, OCCURENCE: 2 TIMES]
[INFO: CHARACTER a IS DUPLICATE, OCCURENCE: 4 TIMES]
```

Comment: He needs repeating duplicates, so `aa` is considered as a repeating duplicate, but `aba` is not because there is a `b` in the middle.

Comment: There are many things wrong with this: it doesn't do what OP asked about, it prints garbage on the console, it's wasteful in space and time, and it's a whole new class for what's basically a loop (Kingdom of Nouns indeed).