# Regex Pattern To validate count of duplicate character

Tags: java, regex, char

I have a collection of strings, I need to create a regex pattern to filter out the strings that has duplicate character only appear twice.

Eg: `Arrays.asList("abcdef","bababc","abbcde","abcccd","aabcdd","abcdee","ababab");`

Here , I want to end up in a result of `["bababc","abbcde","aabcdd","abcdee"]`

So the duplicate character can be consecutive character or intermediate character .But duplication of a character twice is given precedence over any other duplication count

Eg:**"bababc"** , where `'a'` is repeated twice and `'b'` is repeated three times , since `'a'` is repeated twice it get eligible for the filtering.

I tried with different patterns mentioned

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930086/1450401) this works partially only in case of intermediate character, but takes string without duplicates also
- A variation of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17973807/1450401) , this works partially with consecutive chars after sort the string

Can some one help me ?

Comment: yes, I need to exclude 'abcdef' from list

Comment: Why is 'bababc' in the output? 'b' has a count of 3. Does that mean that the 'a' count of 2 here takes precedence?

Comment: yes char count count of 2 takes precedence, apologies i updated the question

Comment: I can't imagine a pure regex approach here because you need to check for dupe chars before the currently checked char.

Comment: I think the second option you posted works - if you're willing to sort the string beforehand. Just have to set the count to {2} instead {2,}. But then, if you're going to sort it first then you may as well just create a function to parse it. Edit: On second thought, this doesn't work as strings with duplicates of 3 and above, but without a duplicate of 2, would still be caught

Comment: yes ,I tried that  https://regex101.com/r/XN338h/1 , but the problem there is "abcccd", where c occurrence is 3

Comment: is it java....?

Comment: unfortunately . yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is java, I suggest using java to solve this problem instead of regex, it is straightforward, and you can extend it very easily in case there was new requirements:

```
//wordList is your string list
List<String> newList = wordList.stream()
             .filter(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(""))                                                       
             .collect(groupingBy(identity(),ounting())).values().stream().anyMatch(c -> c == 2))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

some static imports:

```
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
```

If we do a little test, just print out the result:

```
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList("abcdef", "bababc", "abbcde", "abcccd", "aabcdd", "abcdee", "ababab");
wordList.stream()
        .filter(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(""))
                           .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting())).values().stream().anyMatch(c -> c == 2))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

We have:

```
bababc
abbcde
aabcdd
abcdee
```

Comment: Or as an alternative to `Arrays.stream(s.split(""))` `s.chars().boxed()`.

Answer (score 0):

Will this regexp help?

```
'^[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*$|^[^b]*b[^b]*b[^b]*$|^[^c]*c[^c]*c[^c]*$|^[^d]*d[^d]*d[^d]*$|^[^e]*e[^e]*e[^e]*$'
```

Test:

```
$ cat abcde.txt
abcdef
bababc
abbcde
abcccd
aabcdd
abcdee
ababab

$ egrep '^[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*$|^[^b]*b[^b]*b[^b]*$|^[^c]*c[^c]*c[^c]*$|^[^d]*d[^d]*d[^d]*$|^[^e]*e[^e]*e[^e]*$' abcde.txt
bababc
abbcde
aabcdd
abcdee
```